# What measures to take to prevent electrostatic if we dont skip a rack unit between servers?

Tags: rack, rackmount

After going through the post [Do you skip a rack unit between servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/27726/do-you-skip-a-rack-unit-between-servers) . We thought to consolidate our rack to save space and to improve cooling in lab. If we put servers without skipping a single gap between server what are the chances of electrostatic and What measures need to take to prevent electrostatic if we don't skip a rack unit between servers?

Comment: Why would there be any static generated between servers if the systems are properly grounded.  Can you point me to a resource that talks about this?

Answer (score 5):

Grounded servers and grounded racks. If your servers are plugged in with proper three-prong plugs into a properly-grounded power source, then they're good. In datacenters, you will often see racks grounded to the cages around them with thick green wire.

The point is, as long as everything is grounded, you won't have a problem with static.

They make little 5$ testers at Home Depot that you can plug into a three-prong outlet and it will tell you if it is not properly grounded.

Comment: To be on safer side i wanted to confirm. Generally we had a practice to keep space between servers and someone told me that if we stack server without gap it will electrostatic which can damages ethernet ports/memory etc .

Comment: Any electrostatic issues are likely to be worse with space between the servers.  Without space there is likely to be contact between the servers which will prevent a charge from building between adjacent servers.  Follow good grounding practices always.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your server units are earthed via their mains connection you will be fine while running. If you need to hot swap parts you should take full ESD precautions, i.e. wrist band. As you would anyway.